# override ToString() for an int element in a class

Tags: c#, .net

i would like to override the `ToString()` method for an int (that is a part of a class) so that if the value of the int is 0, the `ToString()` should return an empty string `""`.Can this be done?

**UPDATE**
It would be easy to just create a

```
public string AmountToString {
    get { if (Amount != 0) return Amount.ToString(); else return ""; }
}
```

i was just curious to see if it could be implemented (the ToString() ) on an primite type

Comment: Not unless it's a method of that class, you can't change the int's implementation of `ToString()`.

Comment: You can implement a class that encapsulates int, see my code bellow, but notice that it might act ambigious in some expressions.

Comment: +1 very nice question. These things come up more often than we'd imagine, and few people (me included) solve them in the most elegant fashion.

Comment: @zmilojko i was interested in implementing it without having to declare the int in another class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three main approaches:

#### Employ a [(custom) Format provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

So you can use i.ToString(formatprovider);

**Edit** I think I found a custom format string one that works with the default .NET number format provider:

```
i.ToString("0;-0;"); // works
```

Another sample lifted from the page on [The ";" Section Separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator):

```
i.ToString("##;(##);**Zero**"); // would return "**Zero** instead
```

> ### Tip:
>
> You can d[ownload the Format Utility](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209564), an application that enables you to apply format strings to either numeric or date and time values and displays the result string.

#### Extension method

```
public static string ToStringOrEmpty(this int i)
{
    return (0==i)? string.Empty : i.ToString();
}
```

#### Accessor Helper:

```
class X
{ 
      int member;

      public string getMember() { return (0==member)? string.Empty : member.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the format provider. that makes existing code still work as before

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. You need to have access to the class code to override any methods or properties, including the `ToString` method. As `int` is a primative type, you are not able to change the classes code (not with ease and not reliably anyway).

Your best option would be to create an Extension method:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static ToStringOrEmpty(this int value)
    {
        return value == 0 ? "" : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not unless it's a method of that class, you can't change the int's implementation of `ToString()`.

Some options:

1. Create a method on the class.
2. Create an extension method for `int`, however, you'd have to manage calling it (as opposed to `ToString` yourself).
3. Another option is to create a wrapper around int, with implicit conversion operators etc., that implements `ToString` how you want, and use that in your class.
4. Create or find a custom format provider that you can pass to `ToString`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an extension method, in the same namespace and override the behavior for int class. A sample Example :

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(5.Convert()); // Prints "5"
    Console.WriteLine("Empty String" + 0.Convert());
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class ExtMethods{
    public static string Convert(this int value)
    {
        return value == 0 ? string.Empty : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the ToString method on the (your) class itself and when it is called, simply return string.Empty when this field is 0.

```
return a+i==0?string.Empty:i+...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write a type that inherits from int, **but** unfortunately int is a sealed class, so you can't.

Comment: `int` isn't a class, much less a sealed one; it's a struct and so inheritance isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I thing, it is better to write som extension method instead...

```
public static string ToMyString(this int input)
{
    return input == 0 ? string.Empty : input.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of a way to do that before nor did I find one when searching.
You can use a custom class that holds an int and has its own overridden toString(). is that relevant? or do you have to have it as an int?

you can also use

```
x == 0 ? "" : x.toString();
```

that way you get "" if 0 or the tostring

Answer (score 0):

WHat you want to do is override the class whose ToString() you want to implement. Type int is a sealed class, as most base types are.

What you can do is craete a class that encapsulates int, and then implement cast operators and override the ToString() method.

This sounds like a lot of work for something so small, but that is the way to go!

Here is your class (sorry for lousy names):

```
struct b
{
    int myInt;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return myInt != 0 ? myInt.ToString() : "";
    }

    public static implicit operator int(b d)
    {
        return d.myInt;
    }
    //  User-defined conversion from double to Digit
    public static implicit operator b(int d)
    {
        return new b { myInt = d };
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. ADT to the rescue. +1 if you make it a struct (eek!)

Comment: I think I am gonna leave it as a class, but you are free to change it to struct. But thanks for bringing me back to this answer, I noticed a typo.

Comment: ok. I'm curious what your reason for keeping it a class might be.

Comment: laziness... I am now curious, why do you want to make it a struct?

Comment: Because it will perform a _LOT_ better, say, e.g. when you are going to hold a `b[1000]` or a `List<b> list` of some proportion. Also, arithmetic, copying (cloning), parameter passing will all be a lot more efficient. Garbage will be reduced (imagine a class with 15 fields of type `b`. The GC will be tracking 15 more managed references than necessary, while storage could be 4-8x more efficient depending on platform, guesstimating)

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the ToString() method of int as you wont have access to the code, but you can create an extension method on int class with a different method name like ToString2() in which you can return empty string when value of int is zero else you can return the normal value of the int variable.

For reference on how to create extension methods on existing classes, you can refer below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Extension` for Int

```
public static class Ext
{
        public static string ToMyString(this int myInt)
        {
            return myInt == 0 ? "" : myInt.ToString();
        }
}
```